# Eclipse open classes from search dialog

Tags: eclipse

After searching for a literal in Eclipse, I get the whole matches list. Then I click twice on one of the matches and the class opens. If I want to open another match the previously opened class closes and the new one appears instead.

This is normally a good thing but sometimes I want to compare both results. Is there a way to tell eclipse not to close the class opened before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Search` and uncheck `Reuse editors to show matches`.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! I've been searching only in the search view. Is there a way to do it dynamically? I mean right-click and then "open in new editor" or something similar?

Comment: @iberbeu: Not that I'm aware of.